# Infinite loop in interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I've made an AngularJS website working with an API. This API provides few features like authentication (Oauth).

When the API returns a 401 error, it means that the `access_token` has expired and it needs to be refreshed with the `refresh_token`.

I created an interceptor in AngularJS. Its goal is to check if the result returned by the API is a 401 error and if it's the case, it must refresh the token and then, process the previous rejected request.

The problem is that the interceptor creates an infinite loop. After the second failure of the initial request, it should stop but it doesn't.

```js
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window, $injector) {

  return {

    // If the API returns an error
    'responseError' : function(rejection) {

      // If it's a 401
      if (rejection.status == 401) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $injector.get('$http').post('http://my-api.local/api/oauth/token', {
          grant_type    : 'refresh_token',
          client_id     : 'id',
          client_secret : 'secret',
          refresh_token : $window.sessionStorage.refresh_token
        }, {
          headers : {
            'Content-Type'  : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
          transformRequest  : function(obj) {
            var str = [];
            for(var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
          }
        })
        // New token request successfull
        .success(function(refreshResponse) {

          // Processing the failed request again (should fail again because I didn't saved the new tokens)
          $injector.get('$http')(rejection.config).success(function(data) {

            deferred.resolve(data);

          })
          .error(function(error, status) {

            deferred.reject();

          });

          return deferred.promise();

        })
        // New token request failure
        .error(function(error, status) {

          deferred.reject();
          // $location.path('users/login');

          return;

        });

      }
      // If it's another errorenter code here
      else
        return rejection;

    }

  }

});
```

So this code:

- Starts when the first request fails
- Refreshes the token
- Retries the request but fails again (<- I just want to make it stop here)
- Refreshes the token
- Retries the request but fails again
- Refreshes the token
- Retries the request but fails again
- etc...

Comment: this doesn't look right: `return deferred.promise();`. You should be just returning the promise object `return deferred.promise` and not be trying to execute it.

Answer (score 8):

I worked on this in my app. Your refresh request needs to include a config/header variable like `skipIntercept: true`. Then when you intercept this as a failed response, you can check `rejection.config.skipIntercept` variable. If it is true, you go straight to `$q.reject(rejection)`.

Where you have:

```
if (rejection.status == 401) {
```

Change it to:

```
if (rejection.status == 401 && !rejection.config.skipIntercept) {
```

And then above this:

```
     headers : {
        'Content-Type'  : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     },
```

You need to add:

```
     skipIntercept: true,

     headers: {
        'Content-Type'  : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     },
```

PS. [there's an existing solution](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) you can use.

Comment: Your solution works, I don't have infinite loops anymore ! Concerning your "existing solution", it looks great but it is not suitable for all refreshing token stuff, is it ? Is there a way to adapt it to my needs ? I'm new to Angular and I'm a bit lost...

Comment: @Flobesst Take a look at the readme file on the git repo, it explains how to use the interceptor. Basically, the interceptor does everything, except the refresh request itself. You just need to setup an event listener (`$rootScope.$on(...)`) for the event the interceptor throws on a 401, and then fire your refresh request, and then proceed from there.